# No mostrar números negativos en consulta?

Tags: mysql

Hola buenos días quiero saber como puedo mostrar esta consulta sin números negativos , por ejemplo lo que quiero hacer es que tomo la fecha actual y la fecha de entrega y muestro los días que faltan para que se cumpla dicha fecha , pero quiero que cuando se pase de la fecha de entrega no me muestre números negativos si no que me muestre un `0`.

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2018-08-23', fechaentrega ) AS dias ,
       idequipo , fechaingreso , codigosistema , 
       consecutivolab , codigoreferencia , descripcion, 
       consecutivos , estado , idcliente , 
       sintomas , fechaentrega , solucion 
from equipos
```

En este caso la fecha entrega es `2018-08-23` y muestra esto, lo que quiero es que en vez de que me muestre números negativos me muestre `0`, "`días`" es un *alias* que cree para la consulta no es un campo de la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has probado con [`IF` (ver documentación)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución más sencilla es usar la función [`IF()` (ver documentación)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
  IF(
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2018-08-23', fechaentrega ) > 0,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2018-08-23', fechaentrega ),
    0
  ) AS dias,
  idequipo, fechaingreso, codigosistema,
  consecutivolab, codigoreferencia, descripcion,
  consecutivos, estado, idcliente,
  sintomas, fechaentrega, solucion
FROM equipos
```

Puedes ver un [ejemplo online aquí](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/26qQCckPe9JAbtNZqmnsi1/0).

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, apenas estoy empezando a programar y por eso estoy tan perdido perdón.

Comment: No te preocupes, es normal que no se conozcan todas las opciones cuando se comienza en este mundillo. Te recomiendo hacer uso de la página que enlazo en la respuesta para ver qué te puede ofrecer MySQL (y también varios ejemplos de uso). ¡Un saludo!